# Same GCM message in two applications

Tags: android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

I have library project which has a `GCMIntentService`.

Two other projects: project A and project B (which are using the library project) receive the same GCM messages. There are some messages for project A, some for project B, and some for both of them.

If there is a message for both applications, I want only one of those projects to process that message. Let's say I receive an email. Both applications receive a GCM message but only one should display a notification.

Is it possible to process a broadcast in specific order? How can I know if the other application has already processed this GCM message?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to send the same message to both applications, you have to send the message twice, since each application will have a different registration ID for the same device.

Now, if you want to know, at the client side, which notification arrived first, you can create/update some file on the external storage, which is accessible by both apps. For example, you can assign an ID to the notification (which will be the same for both notifications), and create a file whose name is that ID. The first app that gets the notification will create that file. The second will see that it already exists.